# R jupyter notebook handling table extracted data

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am extracting table data from [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/51143/000005114313000007/ibm13q3_10q.htm)

After extracting, it is getting displayed but in the last lines after every table:

> (Amounts may not add due to rounding.)
>
> (The accompanying notes are an integral part of the financial statements.)

are getting added at the end of the table in every cell. How shall I remove these and reformat the table?

Comment: remove the last few cells in the table

Comment: The problem you are experiencing does not come from jupyter-notebook, but it stems from the way you extract the data. Post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing how you extract the data, and someone might be able to help you.